# Could you help me with what the error is?

Tags: selenium

```
import static org.junit.Assert.;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
public class excel {
    WebDriver driver;
        @Before public void setUp() throws Exception {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\IVS Files\Selenium\Drivers\chromedriver v2.43\chromedriver.exe""); 
            driver.get("http://10.82.180.36/Common/Login.aspx"); 
            driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
            driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000,TimeUnit.MILLISECOND);
        }
        @After public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            driver.close();
        }
        @Test public void test() throws
        IOException, InterruptedException {
            driver.findElement(By.id("body_txtUserID")).sendKeys("donhere");
            driver.findElement(By.id("body_txtPassword")).
            sendKeys("don@123");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id="body_btnLogin "]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("GeneralTabMenu_pnlCustomer_TopMenu")).click();
            String path ="https://infosystechnologies-my.sharepoint.com/personal/doddi_suvarna_ad_infosys_com/Documents/Book1.xlsx";
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(path);
            XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet1 = book.getSheetAt(0);
            int rowcount = sheet1.getFirstRowNum();
            System.out.println(rowcount);
            for (int i = 0; i <= sheet1.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                double loanamount =sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
                int month =(int) sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).
                getNumericCellValue();
                String la = String.valueOf(loanamount);
                String m = String.valueOf(month);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                WebElement name =driver.findElement(By.id("body_cph_Loans_ddlLoanName"));
                Select name1 = new Select(name);
                name1.selectByIndex(1);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                driver.findElement(By.id("body_cph_Loans_txtReqLoanAmount")).sendKeys(la);
                driver.findElement(By.id("body_cph_Loans_txtNoOfEMI")).sendKeys(m);
                driver.findElement(By.id("body_cph_Loans_btnViewEMI")).click();
                String abc =driver.findElement(By.id("body_cph_Loans_lblEMIAmountText")).getText();
                driver.findElement(By.id("body_cph_Loans_btnReset")).click();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: provide with [Minimum Reproducible Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you add the traceback on the bottom for your code. I ran it through a beautifier to try to make it look better for everyone else.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

driver.get("http://10.82.180.36/Common/Login.aspx");
driver = new ChromeDriver();

You should first create object and then launch url...

driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://10.82.180.36/Common/Login.aspx");